# How to find waypoint IDs?

Tags: navigation, website, datasets

Is there a website to find waypoint ID's from coordinate values?

I am looking for waypoints in the Indian ocean area.

Answer (score 5):

One possible source is [Skyvector](http://skyvector.com/)

[image]

You can use it like a paper map using the Latitude and Longitude markings to find waypoints (or other positions).

E.g. What waypoints and routes are near S30°0.00' E112°00.00'

[image]

Hints: Click "World Hi", use your mouse's scroll-wheel to zoom, play with "Layers".

---

There are also sites with lists, by region, of waypoints with coordinates. One example is [fallingrain](http://www.fallingrain.com/world/index.html)